# VBA notation - backslash in quotations

Tags: vba, excel

A colleague at work made a macro and I need to edit it, but first I need to figure out how it works.

```
    Sheet2.Pictures.Insert(importPath & "\" & partName & "\" & picName & ".png").Select
```

This line is (I think) where images are inserted into the excel document. I'm trying to figure out exactly how it works. I know importpath, partName and picName are variables he defined earlier. importPath is self explanatory, I don't know why part name is in there but I know what it is and picName is there because you enter the picture name in a certain cell and it searches for that name in the importPath to insert into the sheet.

Also what confuses me is the & and "\" I have no idea what these do.

Any help out there?

Comment: If (1) you know so little VBA you do not know the concatenate operator and (2) you do not recognise a path, you should not be amending this macro.  If importPath = "A" and partName = "B" and picName = "C", this creates a new string: "A\B\C.png".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is compiling a group of variables into a String that represents a path.  For example, if:

```
importPath = "myPics"
partName = "2014"
picName = "flower"
```

Then the line

```
importPath & "\" & partName & "\" & picName & ".png"
```

will create the String

```
"myPics\2014\flower.png"
```

which is the full filename being passed to `Sheet2.Pictures.Insert`

Comment: OK, I understand that, thanks. partName put me off because it's something the user defines himself in the sheet. So it uses names that the user puts into the excel sheet to search of images in a folder and inserts them at that cell. What I'm trying to do is to remove the need to put the picName in manually and have excel insert the name as well as the picture. The pictures will be numbered 1 to n plus a meaningful name so I think it has something to do with that.

Comment: Ok, are you able to retrieve the `partName` piece of the path from anywhere else?  Also, if you're happy with this answer, can you please click the big green tick?  Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to give you rep but I can't until I have 15 myself :/ The partName variable is OK as it is, it is value of a cell on Sheet2 that never changes so it can be put in once and it never changes. I'm trying to eliminate having to enter the picName manually (dealing with 200-250 images here). So I'm thinking it searches for the first character of the picName, inserts it and moves to the next. I know the logic, just not how to code it.

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing a full file path to an image in that line so the `&` concatenates all the string variables and the `"\"` is just manually adding the backslash characters you'd expect to see in any windows explorer or command line window.